# Less broad app-visibility method should be used

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, android-permissions

We’re using the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission to provide a list of user-installed apps to block from being opened (similar to screentime apps). The user can select which apps to block (e.g. Facebook, Instagram…). So far we’ve been relying on QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES to provide that list of apps and filter them by category.
Now, Google has rejected the app with this reason:

> Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used
>
> We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES
> permission because the declared task can be done with a less broad
> app-visibility method.

They recommend using a "Less broad app-visibility method". But what is that less-broad API they‘re talking about?

Any help/guidance appreciated

Answer (score 2):

> But what is that less-broad API they‘re talking about?

Add [a `<queries>` declaration](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#intent-filter-signature) set up for launcher activities:

```xml
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent>

  </queries>
```

Comment: Thanks! That means I have to add that for every app I’m planning to block? That could be a couple of hundred…

Comment: @DeveloBär: No, you add it once. There is nothing in that XML that is tied to any specific app.